# Is there a special syntax for declaring functions when using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I can not find any reference about this and I see many different approaches.
Someone told me that if you are using jquery in your project you should use a "special" syntax for defining your functions.

What he told me is this:

```
$.functionName = function (var1, var2){
       //your code
};
```

And use it like this:

```
$.functionName("Test", "Test");
```

But then I went looking for a guideline or a best practice for defining functions when using jQuery. And I found this: [jquery4u.com](http://www.jquery4u.com/jquery-functions/5-ways-declare-functions-jquery/#.T9HQh7Xhe2Y)

I think that the above example probably is a function with a 'custom' namespace? I'm not sure.

Anyways, my question is: Is there a guideline / best practice to define functions when you are using jQuery? (and what are the (dis)advantages)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: A simple question: why all this?

Comment: What is the role of that function?

Comment: That _someone_ is the best person to answer this question.

Comment: We are building a project that should be able to handle a lot of requests in a short time span and want it to perform as good as possible.

Also we want our code to be clean and maintainable. 

And also because I'm curious.

Comment: @chumkiu because he wants to learn how to this it also via this way. stop teaching people how to think

Comment: @RoyiNamir it's a legitimate question. If he want an help, we should know the context and the approach to problem... and not last: if I don't see any reason for do that, I can see another point of view and to learn something too me. So... my original comment was simply "why?" but the comment must be > 10 character and I added some word boundary: if this seems "prig", my apologize :-)

Comment: @chumkiu, not a problem. As I said, I just want to learn and keep my project clean so other people can also maintain it when I am out of the office.

Comment: @Nielsm I tried to explain as better for my poor english and my experience :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For define function is not mandatory to use jQuery. Simply define a function in old way style:

```
function myCoolFunc() {
    // your code here
}
```

Now, jQuery is simply an Object (named `$`)… So, if you have this:

```
var myObj = {}
myObj.myCoolFunc = function() {
    //your code here
}
myObj.myCoolFunc();
```

or if you have this:

```
// include jQuery <script ...
$.myCoolFunc = function() {
    // your code here
}
$.myCoolFunc();
```

is the same.. the only difference is that in the first case you have `myCoolFunc` as property of `myObj` object, in the second case the `myCoolFunc` is a property of jQuery object (`$` or `jQuery`).

**What is `$.fn`?**

The `$.fn` is the prototype of jquery object.

To have this:

```
$.fn.myCoolFunc = function() {
    // your code here
}
```

is not the same of previous cases. In this case you declare a public method for jquery instances.
For call this you have to do:

```
$('div').myCoolFunc();
// and not $.myCoolFunc();
```

in this case the function is called for each div in your DOM. Inside the function you have the scope (`this`) that is the element of your DOM.

Finally, maybe it has sense to insert a function inside the jQuery object (LIKE a namespace) in some cases.
If you want a function for manipulate some element in DOM, you should use `$.fn.myFunc` (as best practice).
In other cases, it's faster and logic to put your functions in the global scope (or in other objects for encapsulate it)

Comment: thanks @chumkiu, I think this covers it all :)

So basically it is better that I create my own namespace rather than putting it all in the jQuery object? Except if I want to manipulate elements in the DOM.

Comment: Yes, I think is the better approach :-)

Answer (score 4):

Using jQuery in your project doesn't mean that you should change everything about the Javascript that you use in the project. jQuery is a library, it's not a framework.

A regular function should be defined in the ordinary way:

```
function functionName(var1, var2){
  //your code
};
```

You might consider to put the functions in objects to keep the global scope as clean as possible, but putting every function in the jQuery object using `$.functionName=...` is not any better than putting them in the global scope.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry, still focus....

Your way to write a function is true...
Because `$` or `jQuery` are a variable that declared when page loaded....
I think he is tell about special syntax...

The Special syntax is:

```
(function($) {
    $.functionName = function (var1, var2){
    //your code
    };
})(jQuery);
```

the code above for make sure if this function is jquery plugin

```
$.functionName = function (var1, var2){
   //your code
};
```

the code above is defining function without selector and

```
$.fn.functionName = function (var1, var2){
   //your code
};
```

for including selector

Hope it help

Comment: Isn't this how you create a plugin to jQuery?

That is not what we want to do. We are just building up a simple user interface based on some JSON streams we get from a service.